# How do you list all the files managed by `puppet`?

Tags: configuration, puppet

I need to make some changes to a system but I am not sure if the changes I make are managed by `puppet` or not. So I want to check to see if `puppet` is managing the files I wish to change.

**How do you list all the files managed by `puppet`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ever since version 2.7.x you can do:

`cat $(puppet agent --configprint resourcefile)`

([source of solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/H6dNlGJWTN8))

Comment: additionally you oftentimes need to run puppet agent with the `--noop` option to see any other changes that may be enacted.